# Java databases end user

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am debating what database to use for storing some simple data from a Java GUI.  Is there a database that I can use with java where the end user can simply run the program and it work directly with a database file without adjusting computer settings?  I've thought of trying mysql, but it seems I'd have to adjust settings on every computer in which I'd run the program.  By adjusting settings I refer to requiring downloading specific drivers or setting up a server, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related, but separate, issues at play here: whether to use some specific small or embedded DB for your app, and whether or not to expose DB choice to clients.

If you look at how application servers do this, you often see that specific vendor driver APIs are "wrapped" to provide a standard internal interface to DB accesses. The notion is that some subset of all RDBMs are "supported" (usually by supplying a jar directly, or providing a download link for a jarfile) and some configuration directs the startup code to select, connect to, initialize, and manage the specific database connection(s).

So, your first decision is whether you want clients to install their own supported RDBMs at the supported version(s), or you ship your own embedded DB that they don't necessarily change. The former will take a little design so you can abstract out the connection details, default settings, startup code, schema initialization and (maybe) connection pool details.

The latter could be as easy as shoving a jarfile into your package and calling that API directly as you need to, perhaps only wrapping it enough to create a connection pool.

Wrapping the driver APIs (which can get tricky because some have native components) is also a good way for you to insulate yourself from vendor specifics, so it is a good thing even if you don't ever think you will expose or change the DB(s) you support.

Pure Java DBs like Derby, et al, are pretty well insulated from this sort of vendor specific cruft, but once you get into the enterprise DB space, it is surprising how much the "standard JDBC" interfaces can differ.

Comment: Thank you for all the great information.

Answer (score 1):

There are some pure Java SQL database systems which can be run in embedded mode. You only have to distribute an additional JAR file to your customer.

Look for [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) or [H2](http://www.h2database.com/).

Comment: And don't forget HSQLDB (I personally like it better than H2 and Derby seems to have too many limitations)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you briefly comment on what you like about HSQLDB over H2, please? I really would love to read about that from someone knowledgeable. I'm using H2 now (with JPA/Hibernate) and have used HSQLDB in the past but can't make a judgement because never felt disappointed by any of them.